# Generic XML Content Management System

Tags: xml, content-management-system, content-management

I'm looking for an open source or commercial tool that we can adapt/extend to our existing base of complex XML.

I'm not looking for a CMS to manage website, I'm looking more for one focused on generic XML. I'm mainly looking for a tool to manage XML for client/server game development where the XML represents things like items in the game, quests in the game, and other game systems.

More importantly I'm looking for a tool that will provide a form-based GUI with the ability to do things like:

- Constrain values to values defined in other XML (e.g. similar to foreign key constraints)
- It'd be nice if it were webbased with a central repository (if it could persist to XML that'd be ideal so there's no intermediate authoratative persistence like a SQL DB).
- It's easy to import/export the XML so that we could edit it outside the tool and stay in sync (more importantly we can branch and merge easily)
- Allows customizable UI if we want to build a custom flash editor for some data to be able to submit that to whatever datastore it provides

I'd also like to avoid things that require XSD schemas etc (as most of the time a good tool can just use an example XML to figure out the intended schema, with some manual tweaking). Although it's not that big of a deal as there are tools that exist to generate schemas from XML instances (again reasons I don't really like XML schemas as they can be inferred based on the data).

I've found a good site with a list of CMS's but most if not all are for managing website CMS data.
 - http://www.webi.org/cms.html

Comment: "(as most of the time a good tool can just use an example XML to figure out the intended schema, with some manual tweaking)." I've been working with XML for a few years now and I've yet to see such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

See Ron Bourret's comprehensive survey of XML databases http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/XMLDatabaseProds.htm - there's a wide variety of approaches and what you select may depend very much on the way you model your data or documents